# Give an unique 6 or 9 digit number to each row

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to assign an unique 6 or 9 digit number to each new row only with MySQL.

**Example :**

```
id1 : 928524
id2 : 124952
id3 : 485920
...
...
```

P.S : I can do that with php's `rand()` function, but I want a better way.

Comment: Can you use an autoincrement column?

Comment: No, this is not an option in my case.

Comment: @sans481 with rand I see only one problem : what if that number already exists in the db? (it wil have to generate another one.. that takes time, maybe it can do that by itself, without my intervention :)? )

Comment: Hi John, there is no way to do this automatically sorry. With a 6 digit number, or a 9 digit number the chance of a collision is very slim so just do it. If you have to go through it two or three times if there ARE collisions then its not going to be perceptable to the user.

Comment: Hi Thomas, Yes you're right the chance of a collision is very slim, I just wanted to know if there is a better way to do that.

Comment: Yeah, cool, then unfortunately for you the answer is no. I don't know what you're trying to do, but I would have the id as an auto-increment field. If you're trying to make some sort of secure login system or something then you could always hash the username or something to create a unique, obfuscated string.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL can assign unique continuous keys by itself. If you don't want to use rand(), maybe this is what you meant?

Comment: If first row has id "300" I don't want next row to have id "301".

Comment: Why? What possible reason would you have for this? Is this for obfuscation?

Comment: In my case, each user will be able to create new pages, example : domain.com/124859, I don't want users to access every created page just by adding "1" to their pages... That's the reason why I need random ID's.

Comment: If that's what you're after, and you don't want to risk collisions, consider a cryptographic hash that's guaranteed not to have short cycles/collisions; e.g., MD5HASH of the auto-incremented page ID (plus a salt to keep people from guessing).

Comment: This use case suggests you create a permission system, not obfuscated ids!

Comment: I agree, that's what I wrote too. But I like the question, even though this wouldn't be a good use for unique hashes.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you manually set the `ID` of the first row to 100000, then tell the database to auto increment. Next row should then be 100001, then 100002 and so on. Each unique.

Comment: I don't want something like that. If first row has ID : 100000 I don't want following row to have ID : 100001.

Comment: Well, can you be more precise on what you want?

Comment: Each registered user on my website will be able to create pages like : domain.com/928481, I want the pages to have random ID's so another people cant access them if they don't have a link. (with autoincreement, problem is that the next row will be = previous row + 1, so users can easily find them.)

Comment: Ah. Capiche. You want users to have random user IDs. Well, you might want to consider something else than a six digit combination. After all, guessing one in a million isn't very hard. How about you add some letters? My best suggestion is either to use the username, as it's probably harder to guess, or perhaps a hash of the username. Any way, the best solution is to do this programmatically. This isn't a feature of mysql

Comment: Using scrambled IDs so that people cannot sequentially download all your content is fine, but using them to control access is a BAD IDEA. For starters, any time your users create a link on their page and click on it they will expose their URL to the destination server. Obfuscation is no substitute for access control: Use authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know why you would ever want to do this but you will have to use php's rand function, see if its already in the database, if it is start from the beginning again, if its not then use it for the id.

Comment: I did that before, until now. I asked this question to see if there is another way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially you want a cryptographic hash that's guaranteed not to have a collision for your range of inputs. Nobody seems to know the collision behavior of MD5, so here's an algorithm that's guaranteed not to have any: Choose two large numbers M and N that have no common divisors-- they can be two very large primes, or `2**64` and `3**50`, or whatever. You will be generating numbers in the range 0..M-1. Use the following hashing function:

```
H(k) = k*N (mod M)
```

Basic number theory guarantees that the sequence has *no* collisions in the range 0..M-1. So as long as the IDs in your table are less than M, you can just hash them with this function and you'll have distinct hashes. If you use unsigned 64-bit integer arithmetic, you can let `M = 2**64`. N can then be *any* odd number (I'd choose something large enough to ensure that k*N > M), and you get the modulo operation for free as arithmetic overflow!

I wrote the following in comments but I'd better repeat it here: This is not a good way to implement access protection. But it does prevent people from slurping all your content, if M is sufficiently large.